# Exception: cvc-elt.1.a Cannot find the declaration of element 'company'

Tags: xml, xsd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBF0r.png)

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<company xmlns="urn:company.Namespace"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xs:schemaLocation="urn:company.Namespace companyxsd.xsd">    
   <companyname>ABC company</companyname>
    <address>xyz street, India.</address>

    <department>
        <dname>Marketing</dname>
        <deptphoneno>9876543210</deptphoneno>
        <deptfaxno>0442456879</deptfaxno>
        <deptemail>marketing@abc.com</deptemail>

        <employee>
            <empid>101</empid>
            <ename>Rishie</ename>
            <emailid>rishie@abc.com</emailid>
            <phoneno>9876543211</phoneno>
        </employee>

        <contractemployee>
            <name>Ravi</name>
            <phoneno>9874563214</phoneno>
        </contractemployee>
    </department>

</company>
```

My xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
targetNamespace="urn:company.Namespace" >
    <xs:element name="company">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="companyname"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="address"/>

                <xs:element name="department">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="dname"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:short" name="deptphoneno"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:short" name="deptfaxno"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="deptemail"/>

                            <xs:element name="employee">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:short" name="empid"/>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ename"/>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="emailid"/>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:short" name="phoneno"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>

                            <xs:element name="contractemployee">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:short" name="phoneno"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>

                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>    
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am still a bit new to XML Schema etc. and have been working to develop some XML and XML schema.

The schema is representative of the structure of my real XML.

Now, when I try to validate my XML, I get this error:

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'company'. [7]

This, I think, is to do with a namespace issue on the company element, but I am not sure.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML isn't valid against the XSD: I get a number of errors such as

```
Description: cvc-maxInclusive-valid: Value '9876543210' is not facet-valid with respect to maxInclusive '32767' for type 'short'.
Start location: 10:46
```

However, you aren't getting as far as that. This must be something to do with the way you are running the schema validation, so you need to tell us which schema processor you are running and how you are running it.

(Incidentally, you should never use numeric types such as xs:integer for phone numbers, since a numeric type assumes that a leading zero is not significant.)